# P&T Contacform plugin: what's the use of the errors if fields are not required?

Tags: plugin-contactform, error

In the [Contactform plugin page](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#usage) there's a code example that's confusing me.

Only the email and message are required in the code, but the fromName field does have an error syntax:

```
<input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}
```

What's the use of the getErrors here? I've tried using rare characters, but no errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ContactFormModel you can manage the attribute 'required' => true.

The example just show how to use the getErrors for each field.

You can delete the ones you dont need.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure about that. Since that attribute requires a hack in the plugin, I'd rather see only the supported errors...